# Enviado parâmetros para outra função utilizando objeto ou hash é uma boa prática?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, parâmetros, estilo-de-codificação

```
Exemplo:

    function atualizar(dados, events) {
      //faz qualquer tratamento dos valores

         var hash = {
           novoValor: dados,
           outroValor: event
         };

      // primeira opção
      return customize(dados, event);

     // segunda opção
     return custom(hash);
    }

  function customize(dados, event) {
     //faça algo
  }

  function custom(hash) {
     //faça algo
  }
```

Quero saber se é uma boa prática, e se tem uma boa utilização para passagens de parâmetros utilizando *hash* ou outros objetos em JavaScript.

Parece estranho eu receber dois parâmetros ou mais e depois manda-los para outra função
para algum tratamento em especial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mais uma vez começo a resposta dizendo que boa prática é fazer certo para a situação específica.

Em geral é comum trabalhar com objetos quando faz sentido agrupar várias informações em um objeto. Passar o objeto ao invés de vários parâmetros deve ser consequência da boa organização da estrutura de dados.

Há quem diga que saber montar bem a estrutura de dados é mais importante que saber organizar bem os algoritmos, eu sou um deles.

Criar um objeto esquisito, sem sentido, sem relação só para evitar passar vários parâmetros faz nenhum sentido.

Tentar evitar um número grande de parâmetros na função sem um motivo plausível também não faz sentido. Há casos que precisam de vários parâmetros mesmo.

No caso específico que você está apresentando, parece ser um caso de agrupar duas coisas não relacionadas só para ter o "benefício" de passar apenas um parâmetro. Isto é bem ruim.

Note que na verdade só há malefício. Dá mais trabalho sem ganho algum. E provavelmente afetará ligeiramente a performance, se tiver, também sem ganho de legibilidade. Pelo contrário, é possível argumentar que está até menos legível.

Não crie objetos artificiais sem necessidade a não ser que seja obrigado por alguma razão. Crie objetos quando eles se caracterizam como um grupo [coeso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) de informações.

Não deixe de passar objetos quando você já os tem. A recomendação é apenas para que não crie objetos artificiais, só para passar como parâmetro único. Não tem nada errado em passar objetos.

Olhando por outro lado, se você tem **muitos** parâmetros é um indicativo que talvez deveria ter um objeto se eles estão relacionados e no fundo fazem parte de algo maior. Se a API que você está usando espera objetos ou tem facilidades se passar objetos, faça. Minha recomendação é apenas para não tornar isto uma regra. Muitos casos o uso de um objeto é o normal, só não deve forçar a situação para utilizar um objeto quando ele não é necessário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).