# O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?

Tags: java, terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Quais são as características de um código com coesão ou acoplamento? Até que ponto isso pode gerar problemas futuros?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a definição do termo acoplamento?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11098/3117)

Comment: Qual o motivo da tag java?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas acredito que é porque ele quis um viés para esta linguagem, apesar do conceito ser válido para outras. Ela é um pouco supérflua, mas não chega atrapalhar e ajuda mostrar a intenção dele, mostra onde está está aplicando e está com dúvida.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Os dois conceitos, apesar de diferentes, estão relacionados. E são muito importantes. Um monte de coisa que você vê por aí sobre o que fazer com o código é detalhamento sobre esses dois conceitos.

## [Coesão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science))

Se refere ao relacionamento que os membros de um módulo possuem, não importa o que módulo significa. Indica se os membros tem uma relação mais direta e importante. Códigos coesos são aqueles de relação forte, onde seus membros estão intimamente ligados e estão ali por um objetivo comum. Membros que não são absolutamente necessários para aquele módulo não devem estar presentes em códigos coesos.

Módulos coesos são aqueles que possuem poucas responsabilidades. Desta forma a manutenção é mais simples e evita efeitos colaterais. Fica mais fácil alterar uma parte da aplicação sem afetar outras partes. Por isto é confundido com o [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). E assim alguns paradigmas que isolam coisa podem ser mais coesos do que outros que incentivam por tudo junto, ao contrário da crença popular.

É importante tirar funcionalidades supérfluas de um módulo e transferir para outro modulo.

Isso lembra um pouco a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) do banco de dados que, em última instância, determina que cada tabela possua apenas uma coluna de dado e **uma** ligação com as demais.

Há ainda uma maior facilidade para lembrar do que os módulos fazem quando eles fazem pouca coisa. O que não é coeso, é confuso, incoerente.

Exemplos óbvios de baixa coesão são módulos que cuidam ao mesmo tempo das regras de negócio, persistência de dados e interação com usuário. Mas existem casos menos óbvios quando você estabelece que um cliente pode decidir quando ele é inadimplente ou quais os vendedores que o atendem. É comum achar que isto pertence ao cliente mas os clientes existem independentes disto, e que clientes são papéis de pessoas em uma organização.

É extremamente comum vermos *designs* com baixa coesão, algumas em exagero, outras na mediada certa. Evidentemente que tentar a alta coesão a todo custo também se tornará um problema de *design*. Tudo tem uma desvantagem. Há casos de alta coesão em exagero. Raramente faz sentido ter um módulo com um único membro.

Formas de coesão (do pior para o melhor):

- Por coincidência - Acontece sem planejamento, pode estar certo ou não. Em geral se considera como a pior coesão.
- Lógica - Membros da mesma categoria lógica, mesma atividade, estão juntos.
- Temporal - Se relacionam pelo momento que são executados.
- Procedural - Formam uma sequência para realizar uma tarefa maior.
- Comunicacional - Quando essa sequência de execuções ocorrem no mesmo dado.
- Sequencial - Quando a saída de um membro serve de entrada para outro membro.
- Funcional - Agrupamento ocorre só porque elas realmente precisam estar juntas para contribuir com algo muito bem definido.

## [Acoplamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))

Se refere ao relacionamento entre os módulos. Indica quanto um módulo depende de outro para funcionar. Códigos desacoplados são aqueles de relação fraca, e não dependem de outros para fazer sua funcionalidade básica. É sempre desejável um baixo nível de acoplamento.

Quando há baixo acoplamento, a aplicação fica mais flexível, reusável e mais organizada. É possível intercambiar partes que se mostraram problemáticas, ultrapassadas ou que exigem novas funcionalidades.

Quando se busca coesão é comum fazer com que módulos novos sejam criados com alto acoplamento e uma nova avaliação se faz necessária para reduzir esta dificuldade.

Em geral o alto acoplamento mantêm o problema da baixa coesão, e de uma forma até mais complicada. Quando há uma mudança em um módulo altamente acoplado, gera a necessidade de mudanças em outros módulos, o que pode ser mais complicado de fazer e gera mais riscos do que um módulo com baixa coesão.

Um exemplo de acoplamento ruim é uma nota fiscal que pega dados de um imposto para fazer o cálculo. O ideal é que a estratégia de cálculo do imposto seja completamente independente e desconhecida da nota fiscal, assim pode ser trocado facilmente.

São raras as aplicações que usam o baixo acoplamento de forma adequada. E quando o fazem, em geral é seguindo um padrão de projeto consagrado. Mesmo assim de forma irregular. O que não seria algo de todo ruim se fosse sempre feito com consciência. O baixo acoplamento acaba tornando, por vezes, as aplicações mais complexas.

Formas de acoplamento (do pior para o melhor):

- Conteúdo - Quando um módulo pode acessar, modificar ou se referenciar diretamente a conteúdos de outro módulo.
- Global - Quando os módulos podem ler e escrever dados globais de um módulo.
- Controle - Quando um modulo irá decidir como outro funcionará.
- Estrutura de dados - Quando os dados de um módulo são passados em uma estrutura de dados passada como parâmetro.
- Dados - Quando apenas os dados realmente necessários para outro módulo são passados como parâmetros

Não é possível eliminar o acoplamento por completo, apenas podemos mantê-lo o mais baixo possível.

Fazer com que módulos (classes) dependam especificamente um outro módulo, que exijam uma implementação específica, que não possa mudar o comportamento específico, ou mesmo que exija um outro módulo quando ele pode resolver de forma coesa, são exemplos de acoplamento excessivo.

Em OOP para reduzir o acoplamento devemos [programar para a interface e não para a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

## Conceitos e paradigmas

Estes conceitos existem pelo menos desde a década de 60. E ao contrário do que muitos acreditam, não é um conceito intrínseco da orientação a objeto. Infelizmente algumas pessoas acham que só existe esse paradigma e acabam escrevendo coisas erradas na internet atribuindo informações incorretas ao que elas conhecem e gostam.

Já estava bem documentando em livros dos anos 70 e foram sendo disseminados nos livros mais atuais que privilegiam um paradigma sobre outros.

Tão pouco estão relacionados à linguagens. Na verdade o conceito transcende a computação.

As ferramentas de engenharia de software são bem antigas e podem ser aplicadas, de uma forma geral, a todos os paradigmas de programação. Quando isto é feito, alguns dos paradigmas que parecem ultrapassados se tornam relevantes.

É verdade que paradigmas como OOP podem ajudar a organizar o código melhor, mas quando a pessoa não sabe o que fazer, ela fará errado em todos os paradigmas. E de fato OOP ajuda em alguns pontos, mas complica em outros. É raro encontrar alguém que consiga definir classes bem coesas e desacopladas. Então estes conceitos se tornaram importantes neste paradigma. Em paradigmas mais simples e livres, quando usados da maneira correta, é mais fácil manter a coesão e o baixo acoplamento. Apesar de trazer algumas outras dificuldades de manutenção.

OOP incentiva a subclasse (herança) que é uma das piores formas de acoplamento existentes. OOP incentiva agrupar todos os comportamentos em uma classe, o que frequentemente é abusado. Para resolver isto uma série de padrões de projeto são criados, o que não seria necessário em outro paradigma.

Não estou dizendo que outros paradigmas são melhores e livres de defeito. Digo apenas que se a engenharia de software for aplicada corretamente, o paradigma não é tão importante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Essa resposta não tem mais votos pq n tem um citação do clean code, code complete ou afins hehe :). +1.

Comment: @rray eu vou melhorá-l mas é capaz de não gostarem porque bati no paradigma queridinho de muita gente :)

Comment: Ótima resposta.

Comment: @bigown excelentíssima resposta para uma excelente pergunta! Parabéns! Se pudesse mandar muitos upvotes faria!!!

Comment: @bigown posso dizer que um método `Coeso` é aquele que faz somente o que foi designado? Por exemplo: Método Inserir (Faz somente Inserção) ;Digo porque já encontrei uns métodos que além de inserção faziam atualizações. Deu muito trabalho para dá manutenção.

Comment: Sim, é exatamente isto, claro que tem que ver cada caso, não é simples afirmar abstratamente o que é coeso.

Comment: @bigown Quando aprendi na faculdade o pessoal implantava sempre essa idéia na nossa cabeça, já deixei o meu +1, sua resposta está excelente. Obrigado

Comment: @Maniero fez uma copia de um livro da resposta, isso está dentro do padrão do Site?

Comment: @itasouza cite a fonte então.

Answer (score 35):

Esses dois conceitos são fundamentais para a `Orientação a Objetos`.

**Coesão:**

> Coesão está, na verdade, ligado ao princípio da responsabilidade
>   única, que foi introduzido por Robert C. Martin no inicio dos anos
>   2000 e diz que uma classe deve ter apenas uma única responsabilidade e
>   realizá-la de maneira satisfatória, ou seja, uma classe não deve
>   assumir responsabilidades que não são suas.

Um código coeso é um código onde as classes e/ou métodos tem uma única responsabilidade. Ou seja, um método com o nome `imprimeSoma()` deve **IMPRIMIR A SOMA** e não **CALCULAR A SOMA E IMPRIMI-LA**. Por quê ??

1. Queremos mudar a maneira de como imprimir a soma: mudamos o método de imprimir a soma...
2. Queremos mudar a maneira de calcular a soma: mudamos o método que calcula a soma

Porém, se um mesmo método calcula e imprime, podemos ter problemas ao mudá-lo, já que estaremos mexendo em partes do código que não precisariam estar sob sua responsabilidade, caso o conceito de `coesão`, ou `responsabilidade única`, tivesse sendo implementado corretamente.
Assim, vemos que a coesão é importante para a `manutenção` e `evolução` dos softwares.

De maneira similar, podemos observar o **acoplamento**:

> Já o acoplamento significa o quanto uma classe depende da outra para
>   funcionar. E quanto maior for esta dependência entre ambas, dizemos
>   que estas classes elas estão fortemente acopladas.

Quando uma classe está `fortemente acoplada` a outras classes, dificulta-se o gerenciamento do sistema, pois quando precisamos efetuar uma alteração em uma das classes, temos que alterar o código em outras classes também.

**Fonte:** [DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-coesao-e-acoplamento/18538)

Answer (score 12):

Sei que o tópico é meio antigo, e já foi respondido, mas meu professor passou um exercício perguntando a **diferença** entre coesão e acoplamento, e depois deu a seguinte resposta. Como achei bem resumida, resolvi compartilhá-la aqui.

> Ambos dizem respeito a módulos de um sistema, apesar de que
>   normalmente são conceitos associados a classes em orientação a
>   objetos. A coesão é o grau com o qual um módulo tem uma
>   responsabilidade única e bem definida. O acoplamento é o grau com o
>   qual um módulo depende de outros módulos para seu funcionamento. O
>   ideal, para que um sistema seja flexível e compreensível, são módulos
>   com alta coesão e baixo acoplamento.