# Entradas iguais saídas diferentes no Java

Tags: java, collection

Estou passando por um problema que não consigo visualizar solução.

Vou tentar descrever o que to fazendo, são muitos arquivos de código, então é o seguinte.

Estou combinando políticas de acesso. Tenho determinada política que tem algumas propriedades como (organização, pessoa a quem se aplica etc.) essas políticas podem ser Obrigação, Permissão ou Proibição, até ai tudo bem. Eu gero essas políticas aleatoriamente onde no fim tenho um conjunto de 48 políticas.

Acontece que eu passo essas políticas pelo meu processamento (que é comparar cada uma duas a duas, de forma que se compare todas) e no final eu vejo quantas vezes foram executadas a verificação.

Só que uma vez sai um número, e outra vez sai outros, mesmo eu acabando de apertar o botão do Java. Não sei se ajuda eu por o código. Creio que seja uma configuração no java. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

O código da combinação é o seguinte:

```
public class CombinaPoliticas {

    public static int count = 1;

    public Set<Policie> combinaPoliticasForbidden(OWLOntology ontology) {

        /* COMBINAÇÃO ORGANIZAÇÕES ENTIDADES */

        Engine engine = new Engine(ontology);
        Set<String> origins = null;

        //List<Organizacao> organizacoes = engine.getOrganizationsObjects();    
        //List<Entidade> entidades = engine.getEntityObjects();
        //entidades.add(new Entidade(null));

        List<Organizacao> organizacoes = new ArrayList<Organizacao>();
        List<Entidade> entidades = new ArrayList<Entidade>();

        organizacoes.add(new Organizacao("Instituição"));
//      organizacoes.add(new Organizacao("Unidade_Administrativa"));

        entidades.add(new Entidade("null"));
        entidades.add(new Entidade("PROTOCOLIZADOR"));
        entidades.add(new Entidade("PROTOCOLIZADOR3"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("MARIA"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("JOSE"));

        List<Org_Entidade> organizacoesEntidades = new ArrayList<Org_Entidade>();
        Iterator iteratorOrg = organizacoes.iterator();

        while(iteratorOrg.hasNext()) {
            Organizacao org;
            org = (Organizacao) iteratorOrg.next();

            Iterator iteratorEnt = entidades.iterator();

            while(iteratorEnt.hasNext()) {
                Entidade ent;
                ent = (Entidade) iteratorEnt.next();

                organizacoesEntidades.add(new Org_Entidade(org, ent));

            }
        }

        /* COMBINAÇÃO OBJETOS E AÇÕES */

//      List<Objeto> objetos = engine.getObjects();
//      List<Acao> acoes = engine.getActionObjects();

        List<Objeto> objetos = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        List<Acao> acoes = new ArrayList<Acao>();

        objetos.add(new Objeto("ProcNURCADesp"));
        objetos.add(new Objeto("Processo"));

//      acoes.add(new Acao("MovimentProcess"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Abrir"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Fechar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Anular"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Criar"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Movimentar"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Acessar"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Gravar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Cancelar"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Gerar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Tramitar"));



        List<Obj_Acao> objetosAcoes = new ArrayList<Obj_Acao>();

        Iterator iteratorObj = objetos.iterator();

        while(iteratorObj.hasNext()) {
            Objeto obj;
            obj = (Objeto) iteratorObj.next();

            Iterator iteratorAcao = acoes.iterator();

            while(iteratorAcao.hasNext()) {
                Acao acao;
                acao = (Acao) iteratorAcao.next();

                objetosAcoes.add(new Obj_Acao(obj, acao));

            }
        }

        /* CRIAÇÃO DAS POLÍTICAS */

        Set<Policie> setOfPolicies = new LinkedHashSet<Policie>();

        Iterator orgsEntidadesIterator = organizacoesEntidades.iterator();

        while(orgsEntidadesIterator.hasNext()) {
            Org_Entidade orgEntidade = (Org_Entidade) orgsEntidadesIterator.next();

            Iterator objsAcoesIterator = objetosAcoes.iterator();

            while(objsAcoesIterator.hasNext()) {
                Obj_Acao objAcao = (Obj_Acao) objsAcoesIterator.next();

                origins = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

                setOfPolicies.add(new Policie("Policie"+count, "Forbidden", orgEntidade.getOrg().getOrganizacao(), orgEntidade.getEntidade().getEntidade(),
                        objAcao.getAcao().getAcao(), objAcao.getObjeto().getObjeto(), "2015-08-18T20:06:14^^DateTime", "2015-12-31T20:06:14^^DateTime", false, origins));
                count++;

            }

        }   


        System.out.println("Total de Políticas geradas: "+setOfPolicies.size()+"\n");

        for (Policie policie : setOfPolicies) {;
            System.out.println(policie);
        }


        return setOfPolicies;   
    }   

    public Set<Policie> combinaPoliticasPermitted(OWLOntology ontology) {

        /* COMBINAÇÃO ORGANIZAÇÕES ENTIDADES */

        Engine engine = new Engine(ontology);
        Set<String> origins = null;

        //List<Organizacao> organizacoes = engine.getOrganizationsObjects();    
        //List<Entidade> entidades = engine.getEntityObjects();
        //entidades.add(new Entidade(null));

        List<Organizacao> organizacoes = new ArrayList<Organizacao>();
        List<Entidade> entidades = new ArrayList<Entidade>();

//      organizacoes.add(new Organizacao("Instituição"));
        organizacoes.add(new Organizacao("Unidade_Administrativa"));

        entidades.add(new Entidade("null"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("PROTOCOLIZADOR"));
        entidades.add(new Entidade("PROTOCOLIZADOR3"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("PROTOCOLIZADOR2"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("MARIA"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("JOSE"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("Unidade_Administrativa"));

        List<Org_Entidade> organizacoesEntidades = new ArrayList<Org_Entidade>();
        Iterator iteratorOrg = organizacoes.iterator();

        while(iteratorOrg.hasNext()) {
            Organizacao org;
            org = (Organizacao) iteratorOrg.next();

            Iterator iteratorEnt = entidades.iterator();

            while(iteratorEnt.hasNext()) {
                Entidade ent;
                ent = (Entidade) iteratorEnt.next();

                organizacoesEntidades.add(new Org_Entidade(org, ent));

            }
        }

        /* COMBINAÇÃO OBJETOS E AÇÕES */

//      List<Objeto> objetos = engine.getObjects();
//      List<Acao> acoes = engine.getActionObjects();

        List<Objeto> objetos = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        List<Acao> acoes = new ArrayList<Acao>();

        objetos.add(new Objeto("ProcessDespacho"));
        objetos.add(new Objeto("Processo"));


//      acoes.add(new Acao("MovimentProcess"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Abrir"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Fechar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Anular"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Criar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Movimentar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Acessar"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Gravar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Cancelar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Gerar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Tramitar"));



        List<Obj_Acao> objetosAcoes = new ArrayList<Obj_Acao>();

        Iterator iteratorObj = objetos.iterator();

        while(iteratorObj.hasNext()) {
            Objeto obj;
            obj = (Objeto) iteratorObj.next();

            Iterator iteratorAcao = acoes.iterator();

            while(iteratorAcao.hasNext()) {
                Acao acao;
                acao = (Acao) iteratorAcao.next();

                objetosAcoes.add(new Obj_Acao(obj, acao));

            }
        }

        /* CRIAÇÃO DAS POLÍTICAS */

        Set<Policie> setOfPolicies = new LinkedHashSet<Policie>();

        Iterator orgsEntidadesIterator = organizacoesEntidades.iterator();

        while(orgsEntidadesIterator.hasNext()) {
            Org_Entidade orgEntidade = (Org_Entidade) orgsEntidadesIterator.next();

            Iterator objsAcoesIterator = objetosAcoes.iterator();

            while(objsAcoesIterator.hasNext()) {
                Obj_Acao objAcao = (Obj_Acao) objsAcoesIterator.next();

                origins = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

                setOfPolicies.add(new Policie("Policie"+count, "Permitted", orgEntidade.getOrg().getOrganizacao(), orgEntidade.getEntidade().getEntidade(),
                        objAcao.getAcao().getAcao(), objAcao.getObjeto().getObjeto(), "2015-08-18T20:06:14^^DateTime", "2015-12-31T20:06:14^^DateTime", false, origins));
                count++;

            }

        }   


        System.out.println("Total de Políticas geradas: "+setOfPolicies.size()+"\n");

        for (Policie policie : setOfPolicies) {;
            System.out.println(policie);
        }


        return setOfPolicies;   
    }   

    public Set<Policie> combinaPoliticasObliged(OWLOntology ontology) {

        /* COMBINAÇÃO ORGANIZAÇÕES ENTIDADES */

        Engine engine = new Engine(ontology);
        Set<String> origins = null;

        //List<Organizacao> organizacoes = engine.getOrganizationsObjects();    
        //List<Entidade> entidades = engine.getEntityObjects();
        //entidades.add(new Entidade(null));

        List<Organizacao> organizacoes = new ArrayList<Organizacao>();
        List<Entidade> entidades = new ArrayList<Entidade>();

        organizacoes.add(new Organizacao("Instituição"));
        organizacoes.add(new Organizacao("Unidade_Administrativa"));

        entidades.add(new Entidade("null"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("PROTOCOLIZADOR"));
        entidades.add(new Entidade("PROTOCOLIZADOR3"));
        entidades.add(new Entidade("MARIA"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("JOSE"));
//      entidades.add(new Entidade("Unidade_Administrativa"));

        List<Org_Entidade> organizacoesEntidades = new ArrayList<Org_Entidade>();
        Iterator iteratorOrg = organizacoes.iterator();

        while(iteratorOrg.hasNext()) {
            Organizacao org;
            org = (Organizacao) iteratorOrg.next();

            Iterator iteratorEnt = entidades.iterator();

            while(iteratorEnt.hasNext()) {
                Entidade ent;
                ent = (Entidade) iteratorEnt.next();

                organizacoesEntidades.add(new Org_Entidade(org, ent));

            }
        }

        /* COMBINAÇÃO OBJETOS E AÇÕES */

//      List<Objeto> objetos = engine.getObjects();
//      List<Acao> acoes = engine.getActionObjects();

        List<Objeto> objetos = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        List<Acao> acoes = new ArrayList<Acao>();

//      objetos.add(new Objeto("ProcNURCADesp"));
        objetos.add(new Objeto("Processo"));


//      acoes.add(new Acao("MovimentProcess"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Abrir"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Fechar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Anular"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Criar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Movimentar"));
        acoes.add(new Acao("Acessar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Gravar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Cancelar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Gerar"));
//      acoes.add(new Acao("Tramitar"));



        List<Obj_Acao> objetosAcoes = new ArrayList<Obj_Acao>();

        Iterator iteratorObj = objetos.iterator();

        while(iteratorObj.hasNext()) {
            Objeto obj;
            obj = (Objeto) iteratorObj.next();

            Iterator iteratorAcao = acoes.iterator();

            while(iteratorAcao.hasNext()) {
                Acao acao;
                acao = (Acao) iteratorAcao.next();

                objetosAcoes.add(new Obj_Acao(obj, acao));

            }
        }

        /* CRIAÇÃO DAS POLÍTICAS */

        Set<Policie> setOfPolicies = new LinkedHashSet<Policie>();

        Iterator orgsEntidadesIterator = organizacoesEntidades.iterator();

        while(orgsEntidadesIterator.hasNext()) {
            Org_Entidade orgEntidade = (Org_Entidade) orgsEntidadesIterator.next();

            Iterator objsAcoesIterator = objetosAcoes.iterator();

            while(objsAcoesIterator.hasNext()) {
                Obj_Acao objAcao = (Obj_Acao) objsAcoesIterator.next();

                origins = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

                setOfPolicies.add(new Policie("Policie"+count, "Obliged", orgEntidade.getOrg().getOrganizacao(), orgEntidade.getEntidade().getEntidade(),
                        objAcao.getAcao().getAcao(), objAcao.getObjeto().getObjeto(), "2015-08-18T20:06:14^^DateTime", "2015-12-31T20:06:14^^DateTime", false, origins));
                count++;
//              
            }

        }   


        System.out.println("Total de Políticas geradas: "+setOfPolicies.size()+"\n");

        for (Policie policie : setOfPolicies) {;
            System.out.println(policie);
        }


        return setOfPolicies;   
    }   


}
```

Eu combino primeira todas as proibições, depois todas as permissões e depois as obrigações e junto tudo dessa forma:

```
Set<Policie> setOfPolicies = combina.combinaPoliticasForbidden(ontology);
        setOfPolicies.addAll(combina.combinaPoliticasPermitted(ontology));
        setOfPolicies.addAll(combina.combinaPoliticasObliged(ontology));
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Estes problemas costumam acontecer porque o código está fazendo muita coisa. Por isto há a dificuldade de isolar o problema. Quando se coloca comentários dizendo que "esta parte faz tal coisa" fica claro que está fazendo coisa demais. Eu sou radical quanto a isto e tenho um princípio que não é compartilhado por muita gente que diz que se você pula uma linha em branco, o método está fazendo muita coisa. Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101. Com métodos coesos fica mais difícil cometer erros e mais fácil achá-los.

Comment: Valeu @bigown! Dei uma lida, muito interessante!

Comment: O erro estava porque em uma certa classe eu tava usando HashSet e não LinkedHashSet como no resto do código. Mas agora deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: Responde e aceita a solução.

Answer (score 0):

O meu código tem duas etapas.

1 - Propagação

2 - Verificação

Acontecia que na propagação eu estava criando o Set como HashSet, e cada vez ele propagava de uma forma diferente... Já na verificação eu estava usando LinkedHashSet, e então ele vinha cada vez de um jeito diferente. A solução foi colocar LinkedHashSet (que mantém a ordem dos elementos) em todas as duas etapas.