# Responsabilidade de manter informações dos itens em uma classe

Tags: java

Segue aí uma questão que preciso resolver urgente:

Considere o código `Venda.java`.

Retire a responsabilidade de manter as informações dos itens vendidos da classe `Venda`, criando uma nova classe `ItemDeVenda`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Venda {

    private List<Double> itemValores = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private List<Double> itemQuantidades = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public double total() {
        double soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemValores.size(); i++) {
            soma += itemValores.get(i) * itemQuantidades.get(i);
        }
        return soma;
    }

    public void adicionarItem(double valor) {
        itemValores.add(valor);
        itemQuantidades.add(1.0);
    }

    public void adicionarItem(double valor, double quantidade) {
        itemValores.add(valor);
        itemQuantidades.add(quantidade);
    }

}
```

Comment: Contas a receber e vender sempre é urgente :). Já vou preparar o recibo.

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida mesmo?

Comment: Como eu poderia retirar as responsabilidades dos itens vendidos da classe Venda e colocar na nova classe(ItemDeVenda).

Comment: Então @DiogoNazareno, creio que você deve reformular a sua pergunta, tentando mostrar o que você já tentou fazer. Dificilmente alguém aqui estará disposto a resolver essa questão sem que, em contra partida, você mostre um esforço. Sua pergunta é muito interessante, pois lida com aspectos essenciais de programação, principalmente programação OO. Separação de responsabilidade é fundamental e sua questão vai nesse aspecto.

Comment: Procure por responsabilidade no SO. Tem muita coisa boa lá. Exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81314/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-conceitos-de-coes%C3%A3o-e-acoplamento

Comment: @cantoni, tou ligado. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 3):

1. > **Pergunta**: O que há em um item vendido?

   > **Resposta:** Valor e quantidade.

   Então, você cria uma classe `ItemDeVenda` com o valor e a quantidade, que são `double`s.
2. > **Pergunta**: O que exatamente representa a classe `Venda`?

   > **Resposta:** Uma lista de itens vendidos.

   Então, você substitui os dois `List<Double>` por um único `List<ItemDeVenda>`.
3. > **Pergunta**: Após colocar o `List<ItemDeVenda>`, os métodos `adicionarItem` não compilam mais. E agora?

   > **Resposta:** Altere os métodos para que uma instância de `ItemDeVenda` seja criada e então adicione esta instância à lista.
4. > **Pergunta**: E o método `total`?

   > **Resposta:** Crie um getter `getTotal()` na classe `ItemDeVenda` que multiplica o valor pela quantidade. Então no método `total()` da classe `Venda`, você só percorre os elementos da lista somando os totais de cada um.
5. > **Pergunta:** E as responsabilidades?

   > **Resposta:** Ao fazer as mudanças acima, você terá os valores referentes a um item de venda, bem como os métodos que operam sobre cada item separados em sua própria classe, enquanto que a classe `Venda` se refere apenas a uma lista de itens de venda com os métodos que operam sobre essa lista. Como resultado, a classe `Venda` não precisa conhecer os detalhes do funcionamento dos itens da venda e os detalhes de cada item da venda não precisam conhecer o conceito inteiro da venda como um todo. O nome disso é *separação de conceitos*.
   >
   > Uma vantagem direta que você obtém disso é manter os valores e a quantidades juntos dentro de um mesmo objeto, ao invés de separados em listas diferentes. Além disso, fica bem mais fácil acrescentar novos campos de itens de venda se for necessário no futuro (exemplo, um campo para dizer se o item foi estornado ou devolvido após a compra), pois eles estarão todos juntos, e não mantidos em listas separadas.