# Temporizador com threads em java

Tags: java, thread, multithreading, timer

Boa noite, galera!

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema cliente/servidor multithread. Vários clientes se conectam e, quando enviam a string `"Ocupada"` 3 vezes, o código sai do `while`, inicia a contagem do tempo e finaliza a conexão com o mesmo. Quando o cliente é ligado novamente, se o envio não for "Ocupada", ele mostra o tempo que ficou desligado. Código a seguir:

```
 while (entrada.hasNextLine() && this.cont < 3) {

                saida.println("Situação?");
                String sit = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println(sit);//recebe situação

                if ("Ocupada".equals(sit)) {                    
                    this.cont++;                    
                } else if(temporizador.getStop() == 0 && temporizador.getDifTime() == 0 ) { // faz o stop e exibe tempo                                                            
                    temporizador.stop();
                    temporizador.difTempo(this.nomeDispositivo);                    
                }else{
                    this.cont = 0;
                }
                System.out.println(this.cont);                            
            }
            //inicia a contagem aqui e só exibe quando o temporizador.stop() for chamado ( dentro do while)
            if (temporizador.getStart() == 0){
            temporizador.start();
                System.out.println("Start no tempo!");
           }
```

A classe temporizador é a seguinte:

```
public class temporizador {

    private static long startValue = 0;
    private static long stopValue = 1;
    private static long difTime = 1;

    public static void start() {
        startValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
        stopValue = 0;
        difTime = 0;
    }

    public static void stop() {
        stopValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
        difTime = stopValue - startValue;            
    }

    public static void difTempo(String nome) throws SQLException {
        String format = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", difTime / 3600000, (difTime / 60000) % 60, (difTime / 1000) % 60);
        System.out.println(nome + " levou " + format);

        startValue = 0;
        stopValue = 1;
        difTime = 1;
    }

    public static long getStart(){
        return startValue;
    }
     public static long getStop(){
        return stopValue;
    }
     public static long getDifTime(){
        return difTime;
    }
}
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente mas para um cliente apenas, já que a contagem não sai de acordo quando mais de um cliente envia `"Ocupada"`.

Gostaria de uma ajuda para implementação do temporizador como thread, de forma que os vários clientes acessem e exiba o tempo de cada um separadamente.

O programa já contabiliza separadamente o número de vezes que cada cliente enviou a string `"Ocupada"` por meio da variável `cont`. Entretanto, no temporizador isso não acontece. Para um cliente a contagem é feita perfeitamente, só que os valores não saem de acordo quando mais de um cliente acessa.

Dentro do `while`, o bloco `else if` é uma gambiarra que fiz (ainda acho que foi a melhor opção) que garante que o `temporizador.stop()` e `temporizador.difTime(String)` não executem antes de um `temporizador.start()`, já que no início do temporizador está `stopValue = 1` e `difTime = 1` e o `this.cont = 0` zera a contagem caso o cliente envie algo diferente de `"Ocupada"`.

```
        Temporizador temp = temporizadores.get(this.nomeDispositivo);            
        System.out.println(temp);
        while (entrada.hasNextLine() && this.cont < 3) {

            saida.println("Situação?");
            String sit = entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.println(sit); // Mostra a situação

            if ("Ocupada".equals(sit)) {
                this.cont++;
            } else if (temp != null) { // Para o temporizador e exibe o tempo.
                System.out.println(temp.measureTimeElapsed().getReport());
                temp = null;
                temporizadores.put(this.nomeDispositivo, null);
            } else {
                this.cont = 0;
            }
            System.out.println(this.cont);// Contagem das vezes que esteve ocupada

            String sql2 = "UPDATE vagas SET situacao = (?) WHERE nomeID = (?)";

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conecta.conn.prepareStatement(sql2)) {
                stmt.setString(1, sit);
                stmt.setString(2, this.nomeDispositivo);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        }            
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
// Inicia a contagem aqui e só exibe quando o measureTimeElapsed() for chamado (dentro do while).            
        if (temp == null) {
            temp = new Temporizador(this.nomeDispositivo);                
            temporizadores.put(this.nomeDispositivo, temp);
            System.out.println("Start no tempo!");
            System.out.println(temporizadores);
        }
```

Comment: Ele deve contabilizar o recebimento de "*Ocupada*" de maneira global (ou seja, três vezes independente de quem enviou), ou ele deve contabilizar separadamente para cada cliente (ou seja, cada cliente tem o seu processamento exclusivo e independente no lado do servidor)?

Comment: Ele já contabiliza separadamente, o cont (que faz a contagem de vezes que o cliente envia "Ocupada") é feito separadamente para cada cliente. No temporizador que não acontece isso, para um cliente a contagem é feita perfeitamente, só que os valores não saem de acordo quando mais de um cliente acessa.

Comment: Não entendi a parte do `else if(temporizador.getStop() == 0 && temporizador.getDifTime() == 0 )`, qual é o propósito disso? Se a string recebida for diferente de `Ocupada`, o que é que ele está tentando fazer? E o `else { this.cont = 0; }`? Em que circunstâncias essas estruturas devem ser utilizadas?

Comment: Essa foi uma "Gambiarra" que fiz (ainda acho que foi a melhor opção), nele o if else garante que o temporizador.stop() e temporizador.DifTime() não executem antes de um temporizador.start(), já que no início do temporizador está stopValue = 1 e difTime =1. e o this.cont=0 zera a contagem caso o cliente envia algo diferente de "Ocupada".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notei que a sua classe `temporizador` contém todos os métodos e atributos estáticos, o que significa que um mesmo temporizador é compartilhado em todos os clientes. Entretanto, você parece querer que cada cliente tenha o seu próprio temporizador.

Vejamos o comportamento do seu temporizador. O método `start()` deve ser chamado primeiro, em seguida o `stop()` deve ser chamado e por fim o `difTime(String)` obrigatoriamente e necessariamente nessa ordem, caso contrário, o temporizador ficará maluco. Isso é um exemplo de coesão temporal (veja sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81337/132)), o que é ruim. E também é essa a causa do seu programa falhar, pois com múltiplas threads ao invés de você ter isso:

`start(); stop(); difTime(String); start(); stop(); difTime(String); start(); stop(); difTime(String); ...`

Terá isso:

`start(); start(); stop(); start(); difTime(String); stop(); stop(); start(); difTime(String); difTime(String); stop(); ...`

E o resultado será o caos.

Vejamos o que dá para fazer para resolver isso:

- A primeira ideia seria utilizar instâncias do temporizador ao invés de manter tudo estático. Assim, cada cliente poderá ter o seu próprio temporizador.
- Além disso, vejo que ao resetar as variáveis `startValue`, `stopValue` e `difTime` no método `difTempo(String)`, você está tentando limpar o temporizador para que ele possa ser reutilizado no futuro. Ao utilizar instâncias isso não é mais necessário, basta você jogar fora a instância antiga (o coletor de lixo a destruirá) e usar uma nova.
- O nome do processo que está sendo medido pode estar dentro do próprio temporizador ao invés de ser informado apenas no método `difTempo`. Assim sendo, o nome passaria a ser um parâmetro do construtor do temporizador.
- Simplesmente ao retirar o `static` dos métodos e atributos e adicionar um construtor vazio (ou apenas com o nome como parâmetro), a classe teria que ser usada como construtor, `start()`, `stop()` e `difTime()`, necessariamente nessa ordem. O primeiro passo para diminuir o acoplamento temporal seria então unificar o construtor com o `start()`.
- Para melhorar ainda mais a coesão, eu substituo o `stop()` por um `measureTimeElapsed()`, que mede o tempo passado desde que o objeto foi instanciado e o retorna na forma de um outro objeto, que contém o método `getDifTime()`. Com tudo isso eu passo a ter um nível de coesão melhor (coesão funcional ao invés de temporal).

E então a sua classe `Temporizador` fica assim:

```java
public final class Temporizador {

    private final String nome;
    private final long startValue;

    public Temporizador(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        startValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public MeasuredTime measureTimeElapsed() {
        return new MeasuredTime(this);          
    }

    public long getStart() {
        return startValue;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

```java
public final class MeasuredTime {

    private final Temporizador temp;
    private final long endValue;

    MeasuredTime(Temporizador temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
        this.endValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public long getStart() {
        return temp.getStart();
    }

    public long getEnd() {
        return endValue;
    }

    public long getDifTime() {
        return getEnd() - getStart();
    }

    public String getReport() {
        long difTime = getDifTime();
        long horas = difTime / 3_600_000;
        long minutos = (difTime / 60_000) % 60;
        long segundos = (difTime / 1_000) % 60;
        //long millis = difTime % 1_000;
        String format = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", horas, minutos, segundos);
        return temp.getNome() + " levou " + format;
    }
}
```

Note que coloquei `Temporizador` com letra maiúscula. As convenções de nomes no Java ditam que classes devem ter nomes iniciando por letras maiúsculas, e não costuma ser boa ideia desobedecer a convenção, embora seja permitido pela linguagem.

Além disso, note que as classes `Temporizador` e `MeasuredTime` são imutáveis, e portanto são muito mais fáceis de usar e testar e podem até mesmo ser compartilhadas entre muitas threads (embora no seu caso, isso não seja o que você quer).

Para usar o seu temporizador, em algum lugar antes do `while` você vai precisar declará-lo adequadamente:

```java
// Em algum lugar você coloca isso:
Temporizador temp = null;
```

Ou então se já quiser começar com o temporizador ligado:

```
// Em algum lugar você coloca isso:
Temporizador temp = new Temporizador(this.nomeDispositivo);
```

Entretanto, como cada cliente tem o seu nome único e você vai precisar de um temporizador por cliente, então você usará um `Map`, assim:

```
private final Map<String, Temporizador> temporizadores;
```

No construtor da classe você o inicializa:

```
temporizadores = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(16);
```

Observe que as implementações mais comumente utilizadas (`HashMap` ou `LinkedHashMap`) não são propícias para serem acessadas por múltiplas threads, e por causa disso usamos o [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (do pacote `java.util.concurrent`).

Mais abaixo, o seu laço fica assim:

```java
Temporizador temp = temporizadores.get(this.nomeDispositivo);

while (entrada.hasNextLine() && this.cont < 3) {
    saida.println("Situação?");
    String sit = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println(sit); // Mostra a situação

    if ("Ocupada".equals(sit)) {
        this.cont++;
    } else if (temp != null) { // Para o temporizador e exibe o tempo.
        System.out.println(temp.measureTimeElapsed().getReport());
        temp = null;
        temporizadores.put(this.nomeDispositivo, null);
    } else {
        this.cont = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(this.cont);
}

// Inicia a contagem aqui e só exibe quando o measureTimeElapsed() for chamado (dentro do while).
if (temp == null) {
    temp = new Temporizador(this.nomeDispositivo);
    temporizadores.put(this.nomeDispositivo, temp);
    System.out.println("Start no tempo!");
}
```

Observe que com isso você não precisa mais da gambiarra de definir que os valores 1 e 1 no `stopValue` e no `difTime` têm o significado especial de dizer que o `start()` não foi chamado. Ao invés disso, se o `temp` for `null` é porque o tempo ainda não começou a ser contado, mas se não for `null` é porque ele já começou, o que é mais intuitivo.

É possível que haja mais um monte de melhorias possíveis neste laço ou em outras partes do seu código que sejam correlatas, mas para isso seria necessário maiores informações sobre o contexto no qual ele é utilizado, e provavelmente já seria assunto para uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54197/discussion-on-answer-by-victor-stafusa-temporizador-com-threads-em-java)