# Observer pode ser considerado quebra de encapsulamento?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, encapsulamento, observer-pattern

`Observer` utiliza-se de abstração e `interfaces`. Vamos supor que um `Observer` "assiste" as mudanças de estado de determinada `classe` e os informa a outro agente externo, podemos considerar isso uma quebra de encapsulamento, já que um agente externo tem acesso a essas mudanças de estado?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alguns consideram que sim, em certo sentido. Isso pode ser observado em uma [excelente resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632412/221800). Mas não no sentido da pergunta aqui.

Pelo menos o que é descrito na resposta do SO *linkada* acima é o oposto do perguntado aqui. Ele quebra o encapsulamento do consumidor, a classe que assina uma notificação é que expõe o que não deve para quem ela deseja observar. Inclusive ele é causador de problemas de vazamento de memória se não souber bem o que está fazendo, mas esse é outro problema.

Esse problema poderia ser solucionado sem abandonar o padrão. O problema não é o padrão, é a solução adotada. Isso pode ser visto em [outra pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8764459/221800).

## Outros problemas

Certamente tem problemas maiores. A mesma resposta mostra alguns. [Outra resposta lá no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11626078/221800) descreve outro problema. [Há quem vê mais problema e propõe uma solução com outro padrão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13857084/221800).

Note que isso tem a ver mais com [acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) do que encapsulamento. E talvez o problema do acoplamento tenha mais a ver com a pergunta aqui.

A quebra do encapsulamento ocorre só quando é exposto um detalhe de implementação que deveria ser interno ao objeto. De uma certa forma também é um [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). E esse é o motivo desse conceito ser útil.

## Não chega ser um problema

A questão é se isso é tão importante assim. O fato é que esse padrão vem sendo usado sem maiores problemas há bastante tempo. Os acadêmicos vão achar problemas, vão se apegar aos mínimos detalhes. Os engenheiros vão aceitar que nem tudo é perfeito e se funciona adequadamente sem causar problemas críticos pode ser usado normalmente.

## Algumas confusões

O padrão não precisa necessariamente usar interfaces.

Ele não precisa observar mudança de estado, essa é uma possibilidade. Ele observa alguma ação, a mudança de estado é apenas a mais comum.

Dentro do que está na pergunta eu questionaria: um método `getAlgumaCoisa()` que pega um estado é quebra de encapsulamento? Um agente externo a classe tem acesso ao estado. Não pode? Ou o problema é só observar a mudança de estado? Se é isso, qual seria a solução? Desconheço. Mesmo que use outro padrão ainda ocorreria esse acesso. A premissa da pergunta não faz muito sentido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).