# Query única (dinâmica) ou personalizada?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e estou tentando simplificar minha vida com *querys* básicas de `insert` e `update`, e me deparei com uma questão:

> Devo eu criar uma *query* para cada caso, ou uma que atenda todos os
>   casos, sendo que elas têm a mesma lógica?

As *querys* que eu desenvolvi são estas:

```
//$nome_tabela  : nome da tabela sem o 'tb_'
//$info         : vetor ordenado de informações a serem inseridas          
//
//obs.: os indices do vetor devem ser o nome do respectivo campo
//      sem o '_tabela'
//
private function pdo_cadastro($nome_tabela, $info) {

    //montagem da query dinâmica
    $cont_param = 0;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_$nome_tabela(";

    foreach ($info as $index => $key) {
        $sql .= $index . "_" . $nome_tabela . ", ";
        $cont_param += 1;
    }

    $sql = substr_replace($sql, "", -2);
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $cont_param; $i++) {
        $sql .= "?,";
    }

    $sql = substr_replace($sql, "", -1);
    $sql .= ")";
    //---------------------------------

    //execução da query
    try {
        $prepara = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $controle = 1;
        foreach ($info as $index => $key) {
            $prepara->bindParam($controle, $info[$index], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $controle += 1;
        }

        $prepara->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
}

//$nome_tabela  : nome da tabela sem o 'tb_'
//$info         : vetor ordenado de informações a serem inseridas          
//$campo_id     : nome do campo do código identificador
//
//obs.: os indices do vetor devem ser o nome do respectivo campo
//      sem o '_tabela'
//
private function pdo_edit($nome_tabela, $info, $campo_id) {

    //montagem da query dinâmica
    $cont_param = 0;
    $sql = "UPDATE tb_$nome_tabela SET ";

    foreach ($info as $index => $key) {
        if($index!==$campo_id){
            $sql .= $index . "_" . $nome_tabela . " = ?, ";
            $cont_param += 1;
        }
    }

    $sql = substr_replace($sql, "", -2);
    $sql .= " WHERE ". $campo_id . "_" . $nome_tabela . " = ?" ;
    //---------------------------------

    try {
        $prepara = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $controle = 1;
        foreach ($info as $index => $key) {
            $prepara -> bindParam($controle, $info[$index], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $controle += 1;
        }

        $prepara -> execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e -> getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

}
```

Eu informo tudo que eu preciso no ato da chamada, contando que os formulários foram construídos seguindo os nomes das colunas no DB. Com isso mais o nome da tabela e o campo de identificação (o `id` no meu caso e.g. `id_cliente AUTO-INCREMENT PRIMARY`), eu consigo executar estas ações somente com essas duas funções.

Isso é uma boa prática ou eu devo fazer de fato uma para cada caso?

Comment: Eu prefiro do jeito que está, no futuro pode ser que tenha que fazer uma alteração que seja difícil a manutenção. Recomendo a leitura em: [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81314/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-conceitos-de-coes%C3%A3o-e-acoplamento) que está relacionado a sua pergunta.

Comment: A leitura realmente é muito boa @Marconi Agora sobre a questão do acoplamento, o meu objetivo é, de fato, estabelecer um relacionamento forte entre a interface e o banco e um padrão de nomenclaturas. O acoplamento fica bem alto, porém no mini-mundo deste sistema é exatamente o que eu preciso :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, não sei se eu entendi muito bem o que você quer, mas ao que parece o que você precisa é de uma classe com persistência com o banco de dados que já tenha os métodos pré-definidos onde você utiliza de forma simples sempre que precisar.

Caso seja isso, aconselho que você pesquise sobre **"CRUD"** que significa **(Create=INSERT, Read=SELECT, Update=UPDATE,Delete=DELETE)**, é nada mais nada menos que você criar uma classe com todos os métodos necessários para trabalhar com o banco de dados.

Atualmente existe várias opções de ferramentas já prontas que te poupam desse trabalho chamadas [ORM](http://www.devmedia.com.br/orm-object-relational-mapping-revista-easy-net-magazine-28/27158) **(Object Relational Mapping)**, vou listar os que eu conheço **(Doctrine ORM, Eloquent ORM, ADOdb Active Record)** mas existem muito mais que isso e talvez você pode encontrar algum pode te agradar, digo isso porque para construir uma relação com o banco de dados de maneira consistente eficaz requer muito trabalho e dedicação.

Caso você esteja interessado em aprender mais sobre o assunto, pesquise um pouco mais sobre [CRUD](http://www.devmedia.com.br/crud-com-php-pdo/28873) e [ORM](http://www.devmedia.com.br/orm-object-relational-mapping-revista-easy-net-magazine-28/27158) que vai te ajudar muito.

Na minha época de aprendizagem eu comecei com algo mais simples para entender mais sobre CRUD e a classe PDO (pois ela tem muitos recursos de segurança importantíssimos que vale a pena aprender).

Ex:

Arquivo de configuração: (Config.php)

```
/*
 * Definição do BD
 */
 define('HOST', 'localhost');
 define('USER', 'root');
 define('PASS', '');
 define('BD', 'data_bdTeste');
 define('DSN', 'mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BD);
```

Arquivo de Conexão: (DBO.php)

```
class Dbo
{
/**
 * ---------------------------------
 *  Atributo de acesso à conexão
 *   estabelecida pelo sistema
 * ---------------------------------
 * @var $conn type arrayObject()
 */
static protected $conn;



/**
 * -------------------------------------------------
 * Método Construtor
 * responsável pela iniciação automática
 * após a instanciação ou herança da classe
 * -------------------------------------------------
 * @return $conn
 * @type arrayObject
 *
 */
public function __construct(){

    /**
     * verifica se a variável não está vazia
     *
     * Este método garante apenas uma conexão
     * com o banco de dados e nada mais!
     */
    if(is_null(self::$conn)){


        /**
         * Começa aqui a instanciação da Classe PDO
         * ------------------------------------------------------------------
         * ->Utilizamos aqui as constantes definidas no arquivo Config.php
         */
        self::$conn = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"));

        /**
         * Define para que o PDO lance exceções caso ocorra erros
         * Preferencial para tratamento de erros
         */
        self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    //retorna a variável com o valor da conexão estabelecida
    return self::$conn;
   }
 }
```

Arquivo CRUD: (CRUD.php)

```
class CRUD extends Dbo
{
public $sql;

//Método para a consulta na tabela
/**
 * [listar]
 * @param  [type] $tabela   string
 * @param  [type] $coluna   string
 * @param  [type] $condicao string
 * @return [type]           array
 */
public function listar($tabela, $coluna, $condicao){
    return $this->sql = Dbo::$conn->prepare("SELECT {$coluna} FROM {$tabela} {$condicao}");
}

//Método para inserir registros na tabela
/**
 * [inserir]
 * @param  [type] $tabela   string
 * @param  [type] $coluna   string
 * @param  [type] $condicao string
 * @return [type]           boleano
 */
public function inserir($tabela, $coluna, $condicao){
    return $this->sql = Dbo::$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela ($coluna) VALUES ($condicao)");
}

//Método para o Update de registros na tabela
/**
 * [atualizar]
 * @param  [type] $tabela   string
 * @param  [type] $coluna   string
 * @param  [type] $condicao string
 * @return [type]           boleano
 */
public function atualizar($tabela, $coluna, $condicao){
    return $this->sql = Dbo::$conn->prepare("UPDATE $tabela SET $coluna WHERE $condicao LIMIT 1");
}

//Método para excluir registros
/**
 * [excluir]
 * @param  [type] $tabela string
 * @param  [type] $coluna string
 * @return [type]         boleano
 */
public function excluir($tabela, $coluna){
    return $this->sql = Dbo::$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabela WHERE $coluna LIMIT 1");
  }
}
```

Utilização: (index.php)

```
include "Config.php";
include "DBO.php";
include "CRUD.php";

$crud = new CRUD;
//LISTAR
$crud->listar('table', '*', 'WHERE id=:id ORDER BY id');
$crud->sql->bindValue(':id', 3805, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$crud->sql->execute();
print_r($crud->sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

//Inserir
$crud->inserir('table', "email", ":email");
$crud->sql->bindValue(':email', 'sample@sample.com', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
var_dump($crud->sql->execute());

//Atualizar
$crud->atualizar('table', "email=:email", 'id=:id');
$crud->sql->bindValue(':id',3805, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$crud->sql->bindValue(':email', 'sample@samplenew.com', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
var_dump($crud->sql->execute());

//Deletar
$crud->excluir('table', 'id=:id');
$crud->sql->bindValue(':id', 3805, PDO::PARAM_INT);
var_dump($crud->sql->execute());
```

Abraços!