# Qual o conceito MVC correto a ser abordado?

Tags: mvc, modelo-relacional

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Laravel com o conceito **MVC** e me surgiu algumas dúvidas.

Digamos que eu tenho um **gerenciamento de cliente** (CRUD), então eu tenho uma **View** (Tela com os dados do cliente, Textbox, Combobox ...) tenho um **Controller**, onde eu passo as informações da tela para o Controller e ele é responsável por conversar com minha **Model** responsável por gerenciar o objeto gravando no banco de dados entre outras coisas ...

Por exemplo, em uma situação de **Cliente**, **Funcionario** e **Endereço** logo é possivel visualizar que 1 Cliente ou Funcionário pode ter vários Endereços, e esse modelo seria

- 1 Cliente tem vários ou nenhum Endereço
- 1 Funcionário tem vários ou    nenhum Endereço

Tabelas

Cliente: **idc**, nome, cpf.

Funcionário: **idf**, nome, cpf, cargo.

Endereço: **id** (onde o Id Cliente e Funcionário entra como PK), tipo (Para saber se é cliente ou funcionário), cep, cidade, estado.

**Dúvida 1)** No modelo em questão eu teria que criar um Controller para Endereço ou somente para Cliente/Funcionário e eles já fariam contato direto com o Model de Endereço? 
Ou então eu teria que criar um Controller para Endereço e o Controller do Funcionário/Cliente teriam que acessar o Controller de Endereço e ele faria a ponte para o model?

**Dúvida 2)** Esse modelo está correto?

**Dúvida 3)** Seria melhor eu criar uma tabela endereço separada? ou seja EnderecoCliente, EnderecoFuncionario, Cliente, Funcionario ?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia eu faria assim, criaria uma classe Endereco, uma classe Contato, e uma de cada tabela no banco de dados, vou usar esses dois exemplos porque você poderá usar onde quiser.

Na classe Endereco terá os campos idEndereco, idDonoEndereco, idTipoEndereco, cep, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, municipio, uf.

na classe Contato terá os campos: idContato, idDonoContato, idTipoContato, Telefone(se necessario criar um tabela telefone), e-mail, etc.

na sua classe cliente você poderá pegar os dados do endereco e contato usando o seguinte comando:

```
    public class Clientes
{
   // coloque os campos necessarios
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public Endereco EnderecoEntrega { get; set; }
    public Endereco EnderecoCobranca { get; set; }
    public Contato Contato{ get; set; }
```

}

use este código na tabela vendedor, Fornecedor, Funcionario, Etc.

na sua camada que salva no banco de dados poderá usar os idDonoEndereco e do tipoEndereco por exempo:

Cliente:  IDDonoEnredeco = "O id do cliente"
          idTipoEndereco = "1 ou 2 ou 3", 1 Endereco, 2 EnderecoEntrega, 3 EnderecoCobranca.

Fornecedor: idDonoEndereco = "o id do fornecedor"
            idTipoEndereco = " 4 ", o 4 é do fornecedor

vendedor: idTipoEndereco = " 5 ", o 5 é do vendedor.

e assim por diante quando fizer o select pega o idDonoEndereco e o idTipoEndereco vc terá os dados do endereco é a mesma logica para o contato, e telefones.

assim você usa uma unica tabela de endereco para todos os cadastros.

espero ter ajudado

Answer (score -1):

`MVC` é nada mais que um padrão de arquitetura de software, separando sua aplicação em 3 camadas. A camada de `interação do usuário(view)`, a camada de manipulação dos `dados(model)` e a camada de controle(controller).

**Model**

Sempre que você pensar em manipulação de dados, pense em model. Ele é responsável pela leitura e escrita de dados, e também de suas validações.

**View**

Simples: a camada de interação com o usuário. Ela apenas faz a  exibição dos dados, sendo ela por meio de um html ou xml.

**Controller**

O responsável por receber todas as requisições do usuário. Seus métodos chamados actions, são responsáveis por uma página, controlando qual model usar e qual view será mostrado ao usuário.

**Resposta a dúvida 1:**

Isso depende !! vou explicar

Se você tem uma tela só para endereço o correto seria ter um `controller` somente para endereço. Por outro lado caso a entidade `endereço` é criada juntamente com a entidade `Funcionário/Cliente`  ou seja ela depende da entidade o melhor nesse casso é um `controller` para `Funcionário` onde  faria a ponte para o model `endereço`. Quando você separa as `responsabilidades você tem o ganho de coesão` o que é bom para um projeto `alta coesão e baixo acoplamento` entre as classes falando em `POO`.

De uma olhada nesses conceitos de **coesão** e **acoplamento**.

[O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81314/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-conceitos-de-coes%C3%A3o-e-acoplamento)

**Dúvida 2) Esse modelo está correto?**

Esse modelo está correto?
Não exite algo sempre correto ou melhor para todos os casos. Você tem que analisar o ***casso real para ver o que fica melhor para cada caso ou projeto***. Mais o modelo `MVC` para esse estudo de casso é uma boa opção.

**Dúvida 3**) Seria melhor eu criar uma tabela endereço separada? ou seja `EnderecoCliente`, `EnderecoFuncionario`, `Cliente`, `Funcionario` ?

O correto ou melhor nesse caso é você criar uma unica `tabela` `endereço` para `cliente` e `funcionário`. Com isso evitaria a redundância de dados por que você pode ter o mesmo endereço em dois lugares o que produzia a redundância e também aumentaria a complexidade e manutenção do seu projeto.

**Exemplo  :**

`Cliente` tem 1 ou N  `endereços`.

`Funcionário` tem 1 ou N eendereços`.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite...

pelo que eu entendi da pergunta e da resposta muito bem detalhada pelo nosso colega...

a questão principal é sobre **modelagem de dados** e não **mvc** (especificamente); a questão maior é **integridade de dados**, o sentido de **mvc** ou poo ou conjuntos deve ser(tambem) baseado em **DRY**,(Don´t repeat yourself).

uma tabela **endereço** somente, resolve bem, baseado por essa **tabela** você pode acessar qualquer campo, **PK** ou **FK**.

E sobre o modelo de negócios desse projeto, não acredito que seja ideal um **Funcionario** ou **Cliente** sem **endereço**, até no intuito futuro da analise de  dados.

espero ter gerado mais assunto para pesquisa e estudo de caso, um abraço.