# Como alterar o conteúdo de uma variável de classe herdada?

Tags: java, java-8

estou desenvolvendo um sistema de transações para fins metodológicos.

Tenho a seguinte `classe mãe`  chamada `Conta`:

```
public class Conta {

    private double _saldo = 0;
    private String _nome;
    private int _idade;
    private int  numeroConta;  
    protected String message;

    Conta(int numeroConta, double saldo) {
        this._saldo += saldo;
        this.numeroConta = numeroConta;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return "Nome: " + this._nome;
    }    
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this._nome = nome;
    }
    public int getIdade() {        
        return this._idade;
    }
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this._idade = idade;
    }
   public void setDepositar(double money){
        this._saldo += money;
    }
    public void setSacar(double money){
        if (money <= this._saldo) {
            this._saldo -= money;
            this.message = "Saque efetuado!";
           System.out.println(message);
        }      
        else System.out.println("Recusado! Você não possui saldo suficiente!");

    }   
    public double getSaldo() {        
        return  this._saldo;            
    }       
}
```

No método `setSacar` efetuo uma verificação e dependendo  do resultado ele imprime uma mensagem para o usuário.

Tenho a seguinte `classe filha` chamada `Cartao`:

```
public class Cartao extends Conta {
private int _numeroCartao;
private boolean status  = true;

  Cartao(int numeroConta, double saldo) {
      super(numeroConta,saldo);
  }
public boolean cartaoAtivo(boolean status) {
    if (status) return this.status = true;           

    else return this.status = false;
}
public void comprarProduto(double valor) {
    if (this.status) {            
        this.setSacar(valor); //chamada do metodo
          super.message ="Compra realizada!";// quero alterar essa frase           
    }     
    else System.out.println("Cartão inativo. Compra não realizada!");
}

public void setNumeroCartao(int numero) {
    this._numeroCartao = numero;
}

public int getNumeroCartao() {
    return this._numeroCartao;
}   }
```

E na minha classe `main` estou imprimindo o seguinte:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
          Cartao c1 = new Cartao(1,500);
          c1.cartaoAtivo(true);
          c1.setNumeroCartao(1);
          c1.comprarProduto(100);//realizando a compra

          c1.setSacar(400);//realizando o saque 
          System.out.println("Seu saldo: R$ " + c1.getSaldo());
          System.out.println("Número do cartão: "+ c1.getNumeroCartao());
    }
}
```

Que tem como saída:

```
Saque efetuado!
Saque efetuado!
Seu saldo: R$ 0.0
Número do cartão: 1
```

A questão é: Alterei a frase de exibição na classe filha para `Compra realizada!` mas na saída, a frase continua sendo puxada da `classe mãe`.

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Cartao estendendo conta? Sua modelagem não está legal hein.

Comment: @Articuno, como citei no início, o projeto é para fins de estudos, nem modelagem foi feita.

Comment: Eu li, e como dica, estou te dizendo que não está legal. é como se você estivesse afirmando que `cartão é um tipo de conta`, mas cartão é cartão, conta é conta. E se você quiser alterar comportante da superclasse, não é dessa forma, você precisa criar um setter  para o campo e sobrescrever ele.

Comment: @Articuno obrigado pela dica, o que eu queria implementar mesmo era uma `ContaPoupança` mas ainda estou ajeitando algumas coisas para ai sim substituir pela classe `Cartao` que foi criada apenas para tentar sanar essa dúvida que estou tendo.

Comment: @Articuno criei o setter, até exibe a mensagem da classe filha mas a mensagem da classe mãe também é impressa.

Comment: @JorgeMatheus amigo, não entrando em detalhes da validade da sua arquitetura. creio que se você simplesmente alterar a mensagem antes de chamar o metodo 'setSacar()' ele vai refletir a alteração. Da forma que está ele executa o saque, mostra a mensagem, e após isto você muda o valor da variável 'mensagem'.

Comment: No entanto.. dessa forma, caso você chamar o método setSacar() diretamente pela classe Cartão após uma chamada do método comprarProduto(), a mensagem vai ser a mesma. Ele não vai mostrar o texto original.

Comment: @IsraelMerljak sim é isso mesmo, por isso queria saber um método de alterar a mensagem ao invés de mostra a mesma.

Comment: Ainda mais.. geralmente não é boa pratica você associar uma resposta ao UI (considerando o log no terminal como feedback) a uma classe com a lógica de negócio. O melhor seria você retornar algum resultado desse método setSacar() tipo um boolean, e verificar o sucesso (e setar a mensagem correta) no código que a utiliza (classes filhas, etc)

Comment: @IsraelMerljak pensei na mesma coisa... Pode dar um exemplo para eu ver se é a mesma coisa?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73842/discussion-between-israel-merljak-and-jorge-matheus).

Comment: Não dá pra sugerir algo sem mexer em toda a estrutura do código, não adianta da uma solução e continuar fazendo errado. Você precisa aplicar os principios de [coesão e encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/28595), senão está aprendendo da forma errada e assim continuará pois pra frente será mais dificil reaprender do jeito certo.

Comment: Artículo,obrigado pela sugestão. Vou dar uma lida depois na resposta que contém no link que vc me passou.