# Problemas com paginação na JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou criando uma aplicação onde preencho os dados de uma tabela através do banco de dados, mas são muitos então queria organizar melhor.

Porém, os resultados exibidos na tabela não são constantes. Os métodos implementados se comportam de maneiras diferentes mesmo com o mesmo botão sendo pressionado.

Quando uso o `alunos_1.json`, que tem uma página com menos do que o número máximo de registros permitido, a tabela carrega e tudo funciona da maneira que falei, porém quando carrego um `json alunos.json` que tem um número divisível pelo máximo de registros não funciona.

Classe da tabela

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Teste extends JFrame{
   //MAIN METHOD
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
       {
           public void run()
           {
               //INITIALIZE JFRAME FORM
               teste.Teste form=new teste.Teste();
               form.setVisible(true);;
           }
       });

  }

  TesteTableModel tableModel = new TesteTableModel();
  List<TesteModel> resultado = new ArrayList<TesteModel>();
  List<TesteModel> lista = new ArrayList<TesteModel>();
  int indiceLista, maxLista, resto, totalPag = 0;
  int paginaAtual = 1;

  private static final int ITENS_POR_PAG = 5;

  private java.awt.Button btnRemover, btnProxima, btnAnterior, btnPrimeira, btnUltima;
  private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane;
  private javax.swing.JTable jTable;
  private java.awt.ScrollPane scrollPane;


  //CONSTRUCTOR
  public Teste()
  {
        scrollPane = new java.awt.ScrollPane();
        jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        btnRemover = new java.awt.Button();
        btnAnterior = new java.awt.Button();
        btnProxima = new java.awt.Button();
        btnUltima = new java.awt.Button();
        btnPrimeira = new java.awt.Button();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 400));

        jTable.setModel(tableModel);

        jScrollPane.setViewportView(jTable);

        scrollPane.add(jScrollPane);

        btnRemover.setLabel("Remover");

        btnAnterior.setLabel("<");

        btnProxima.setLabel(">");

        btnUltima.setLabel(">>");

        btnPrimeira.setLabel("<<");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(btnRemover, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 293, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnPrimeira, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnAnterior, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnProxima, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(btnUltima, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 316, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(btnRemover, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnAnterior, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnProxima, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnUltima, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnPrimeira, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        btnRemover.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("btnRemover");

        pack();

        btnRemover.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                tableModel.deletarLinhas();
            }
        });

        btnProxima.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(indiceLista <= lista.size()){
                    btnAnterior.setEnabled(true);
                    btnPrimeira.setEnabled(true);
                    resultado = carregaProximaPagina(lista);

                    for(TesteModel teste: resultado){
                        tableModel.addRow(teste);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        btnAnterior.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                if(indiceLista != 0){
                    btnProxima.setEnabled(true);
                    btnUltima.setEnabled(true);
                    resultado = carregaPaginaAnterior(lista);

                    for(TesteModel teste: resultado){
                        tableModel.addRow(teste);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        btnUltima.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                resultado = carregaUltimaPagina(lista);

                for(TesteModel teste: resultado){
                    tableModel.addRow(teste);
                }
            }
        });

        btnPrimeira.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                resultado = carregaPrimeiraPagina(lista);

                for(TesteModel teste: resultado){
                    tableModel.addRow(teste);
                }
            }
        });

         //Preenche dados iniciais da tabela
        lista = tableModel.lerJSON();

        paginaAtual = (int) lista.size() / ITENS_POR_PAG;
        resto = lista.size() % ITENS_POR_PAG;

        System.out.println("\npagina:" + paginaAtual
                + "\nresto:" + resto);

        resultado = carregaProximaPagina(lista);

        for(TesteModel teste: resultado){
            tableModel.addRow(teste);
        }

        btnAnterior.setEnabled(false);
        btnPrimeira.setEnabled(false);

    }                       

    private void limparTabela() {  
        while (jTable.getModel().getRowCount() > 0) {  
           ((TesteTableModel) jTable.getModel()).removeRow(0);  
       } 
    } 

    public List<TesteModel> carregaProximaPagina(List<TesteModel> testes){
        limparTabela();
        List<TesteModel> resultado = new ArrayList<TesteModel>();
        if(resto > 0){
            if(paginaAtual > 0){
                indiceLista = maxLista;
                maxLista += ITENS_POR_PAG;
                for(int i = indiceLista; i < maxLista; i++){
                    resultado.add(testes.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println("\nindiceLista:" + indiceLista
                        + "\nmaxLista:" + maxLista
                        + "\npagina:" + paginaAtual);
            } else { 
                indiceLista = maxLista;
                maxLista += resto;
                for(int i = indiceLista; i < maxLista; i++){
                    resultado.add(testes.get(i));
                }
                btnProxima.setEnabled(false);
                btnUltima.setEnabled(false);
                System.out.println("\nindiceLista:" + indiceLista
                        + "\nmaxLista:" + maxLista
                        + "\npagina:" + paginaAtual);
            }
        }
        paginaAtual--;       
        return resultado;
    }

    public List<TesteModel> carregaPaginaAnterior(List<TesteModel> testes){
        limparTabela();
        List<TesteModel> resultado = new ArrayList<TesteModel>();
        if(paginaAtual == 0){
            maxLista = indiceLista;
            indiceLista = maxLista - ITENS_POR_PAG;

            for(int i = indiceLista; i < maxLista; i++){
                resultado.add(testes.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("\nindiceLista:" + indiceLista
                    + "\nmaxLista:" + maxLista
                    + "\npagina:" + paginaAtual);
        } else {
            if(paginaAtual == ((int) testes.size() / ITENS_POR_PAG)){
                btnAnterior.setEnabled(false);
                btnPrimeira.setEnabled(false);
            }

            indiceLista -= ITENS_POR_PAG;
            maxLista -= ITENS_POR_PAG;
            for(int i = indiceLista; i < maxLista; i++){
                resultado.add(testes.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("\nindiceLista:" + indiceLista
                    + "\nmaxLista:" + maxLista
                    + "\npagina:" + paginaAtual);
        }
        paginaAtual++;
        return resultado;
    }

    public List<TesteModel> carregaPrimeiraPagina(List<TesteModel> testes){
        limparTabela();
        List<TesteModel> resultado = new ArrayList<TesteModel>();

        totalPag = (int) lista.size() / ITENS_POR_PAG;

        indiceLista = 0;
        maxLista = ITENS_POR_PAG;
        for(int i = indiceLista; i < maxLista; i++){
            resultado.add(testes.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("\nindiceLista:" + indiceLista
                + "\nmaxLista:" + maxLista
                + "\npagina:" + paginaAtual);

        return resultado;
    }

    public List<TesteModel> carregaUltimaPagina(List<TesteModel> testes){
        limparTabela();
        List<TesteModel> resultado = new ArrayList<TesteModel>();

        totalPag = (int) lista.size() / ITENS_POR_PAG;

        if(resto != 0) {
            indiceLista = ITENS_POR_PAG * totalPag;
            maxLista = indiceLista + resto;
            for(int i = indiceLista; i < maxLista; i++){
                resultado.add(testes.get(i));
            }
            paginaAtual = 0;
            System.out.println("\nindiceLista:" + indiceLista
                    + "\nmaxLista:" + maxLista
                    + "\npagina:" + paginaAtual);
        } else {
            indiceLista = ITENS_POR_PAG * totalPag;
            maxLista = indiceLista + ITENS_POR_PAG;
            for(int i = indiceLista; i < maxLista; i++){
                resultado.add(testes.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("\nindiceLista:" + indiceLista
                    + "\nmaxLista:" + maxLista
                    + "\npagina:" + paginaAtual);
        }
        return resultado;
    }

}
```

TesteTableModel

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TesteTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {


    private List<TesteModel> dados = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] colunas = {"Selecionar", "Nome"};


    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0 ? Boolean.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        return colunas[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dados.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
        switch(coluna){
            case 0:
                return dados.get(linha).getSelecionado();
            case 1:
                return dados.get(linha).getNome();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object valor, int linha, int coluna) {
        TesteModel tm = dados.get(linha);
        switch (coluna) {
        case 0:
            tm.setSelecionado(new Boolean((Boolean) valor));
            break;
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void addRow(TesteModel tm) {
        this.dados.add(tm);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();    
    }

    public void removeRow(int linha){
        this.dados.remove(linha);
        this.fireTableRowsDeleted(linha, linha);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0; 
    }

    public void deletarLinhas() {

    for (int i = getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (dados.get(i).getSelecionado()) {
        removeRow(i);
            }
    }
    }

    public String lerArquivo() {
        String linha = "";

        try {
          FileReader arq = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\maily\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Teste\\src\\teste\\alunos_1.json");
          BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

          linha = lerArq.readLine(); 
          /*while (linha != null) {
            System.out.printf(linha);
            linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê da segunda até a última linha
          }*/
          arq.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n",
              e.getMessage());
        }
        //System.out.println(linha);
        return linha;
    }

    public List<TesteModel> lerJSON() {
        String str = lerArquivo();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<TesteModel>>(){}.getType();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        List<TesteModel> lista = gson.fromJson(str, type);

        for(TesteModel teste: lista){
            System.out.println(teste.getSelecionado());
            System.out.println(teste.getNome());
        }
        return lista;
    }

}
```

Classe Model

```
public class TesteModel {
    private Boolean select;
    private String name;

    public Boolean getSelecionado() {
        return select;
    }

    public void setSelecionado(Boolean selecionado) {
        this.select = selecionado;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.name = nome;
    }

}
```

alunos.json

```
[{"select": "false", "name": "Ana 01"}, {"select": "false", "name": "João"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Laura"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"}, {"select": "false", "name": "José 02"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Maria"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Renato"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Paula"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Juliano"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Júlio 03"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Amanda"}, {"select": "false", "name": "André"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Tales"},{"select": "false", "name": "Pedro"}, {"select": "false", "name": "João 04"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Laura"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"},{"select": "false", "name": "Pedro"}, {"select": "false", "name": "João 05"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Laura"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"},{"select": "false", "name": "Pedro"}, {"select": "false", "name": "João 06"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Laura"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"},{"select": "false", "name": "Pedro"}]
```

alunos_1.json

```
[{"select": "false", "name": "Ana 01"}, {"select": "false", "name": "João"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Laura"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"}, {"select": "false", "name": "José 02"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Maria"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Renato"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Paula"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Juliano"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Júlio 03"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Amanda"}, {"select": "false", "name": "André"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Tales"},{"select": "false", "name": "Pedro"}, {"select": "false", "name": "João 04"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Laura"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"},{"select": "false", "name": "Pedro"}, {"select": "false", "name": "João 05"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Laura"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"},{"select": "false", "name": "Pedro"}, {"select": "false", "name": "João 06"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Laura"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"},{"select": "false", "name": "Pedro"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Bruno"}, {"select": "false", "name": "Carina"},{"select": "false", "name": "Joselino RESTO"}]
```

A lib do Gson pode ser [baixada aqui.](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/)

Comment: @lys é muita coisa pra uma resposta objetiva, precisaria de um tutorial (que não cabe na proposta desse site aqui). O ideal seria você ao menos [edit] e dar mais detalhes do que tem, das estruturas, de forma que possamos ajudar. Ajude a gente a te ajudar, e a gente vai orientando por aqui até chegar numa pergunta possível de se responder.

Comment: Por exemplo, você pode postar um código básico sem a parte da paginação, mas com as estruturas que vc já tem prontas, simplificando um pouco. Pq quando você aprender com poucos dados, com certeza vai saber com mais dados.

Comment: Depende de como você carrega os dados. Se você traz todos os dados da tabela de uma vez, eu acho que é perda de tempo fazer paginaçao, nao vale o esforço, porque vai ser apenas visual, o desempenho e custo de memoria vai ser o mesmo.

Comment: Na aplicação final, os dados serão carregados a partir de um JSON.

Comment: @lys editei o comentario.

Comment: Vou trazer de uma vez sim lendo do JSON, mas é um requisito que esta tabela tenha paginação.

Comment: @lys vejo q vc ainda está usando layout absoluto e devido a isso, nao é possivel fazer paginacao de forma eficiente, por causa do tamanho da linha. Sugiro que leia minha dica da sua ultima resposta e mude para layouts relativos, assim fica facil implementar

Comment: Ou posso sugerir uma solucao generica e você olha e estuda como adaptar pro teu codigo.

Comment: Porque voce ta usando joptionpane pra mostrar tabela? A finalidade deste componente nao é bem pra isso.

Comment: Desculpe, mas não estou usando JOptionPane em lugar nenhum. Estou tentando recriar com algum layout relativo para que fique viável a ajuda que preciso.

Comment: Perdão, confundi com um codigo antigo aqui. Só uma ultima duvida, voce vai resgatar todos os dados da tabela de uma unica vez, mas quer exibir eles por paginacao?

Comment: Preciso que apareçam por exemplo, 10 registros por vez. Então, acredito que seja mais inteligente resgatar aos poucos e armazenar o índice que parei para continuar depois.

Comment: Ai você precisaria apresentar um **[mcve]** de como voce recupera dados da sua tabela real, pois o exemplo será baseado nos dados ja constantes na tabela. Sem ver e testar a implementacao real que voce recupera os dados nao tem como sugerir nada que vai te servir.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85244/discussion-between-articuno-hexacampao-and-lys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível fazer isso aplicando a abordagem [desta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175860/5524514), onde apenas limitamos a quantidade de dados a ser exibidos na tela, removendo a barra de rolagem e utilizando os botões para movê-la de forma manual.

O segredo aqui é usar a altura das linhas da tabela vezes a quantidade que se quer exibir para mover a barra rolagem, por isso no listener dentro dos botoes `btnPrevious` e `btnNext` eu calculo a altura do próximo conjunto de linhas. No exemplo adaptado do seu código, a barra moverá verticalmente exatamente a altura de 5 linhas da tabela por vez, até o seu final ou seu incio.

Para os botões que movem para o inicio e final da tabela(`btnFirst` e `btnLast`), eu apenas defino os valores minimo e máximo da barra, fazendo com que ela se desloque para o inicio ou final da tabela.

A tela com a tabela e os botoes ficou assim:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class JTablePaginada extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane, buttonPane;
    private JButton btnFirst, btnPrevious, btnNext, btnLast, btnClean;
    private JTable table;
    private TesteTableModel model;
    
    private static final int ITENS_POR_PAG = 5;
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()-> new JTablePaginada().setVisible(true));
    }


    public JTablePaginada() {
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        
        model = new TesteTableModel(JSONUtils.JSONtoList());
        
        table = new JTable(model);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        //o width é um pequeno "workaround pra tabela ficar certinha na tela
        //a altura é definida pela quantidade de itens que quer exibir 
        //mais a altura do cabeçalho
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width - 20, table.getRowHeight() * ITENS_POR_PAG + table.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize().height));

        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        this.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        btnClean = new JButton("Remover tudo");
        btnFirst = new JButton("<<");
        btnFirst.addActionListener(e -> {
            JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setValue(0);
        });
        
        btnPrevious = new JButton("<");
        btnPrevious.addActionListener(e -> {
            int height = table.getRowHeight() * (ITENS_POR_PAG - 1);
            JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setValue(bar.getValue() - height);
        });
        
        btnNext = new JButton(">");
        btnNext.addActionListener(e -> {
            int height = table.getRowHeight() * (ITENS_POR_PAG - 1);
            JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + height);
        });
        
        btnLast = new JButton(">>");
        btnLast.addActionListener(e -> {
            JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setValue(bar.getMaximum());
        });
        
        buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.add(btnFirst);
        buttonPane.add(btnPrevious);
        buttonPane.add(btnNext);
        buttonPane.add(btnLast);
        
        this.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
        pack();
    }
}
```

Executando com o arquivo `alunos.json`:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Lembrando que não importa a quantidade de dados aqui, pois apenas estamos movendo a barra de rolagem pelas linhas da tabela, sem exibi-la na tela.

---

## Comentários complementares

Fiz outras modificações no código que são importantes para comentar, apesar de fugir um pouco do problema, que já foi resolvido acima, mas podem afetar novas implementações, inclusive da própria paginação:

- sua classe `TableModel` não deveria ler o arquivo json e nem convertê-lo, isso fere o [principio de coesão da classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/28595), além do conceito de responsabilidade única, onde a classe deve fazer apenas aquilo para a qual foi designada. Por isso movi os dois métodos de leitura do arquivo e de conversão do json para `List` para uma nova classe JSONUtils:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class JSONUtils {

    private static String strjson = null;

    
    //isso é pra evitar instanciacao da classe
    //ja que os métodos sao estaticos
    private JSONUtils() {

        if (strjson == null)
            strjson = lerArquivo();
    }

    public static List<TesteModel> JSONtoList() {
        String str = lerArquivo();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<TesteModel>>() {
        }.getType();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        List<TesteModel> lista = gson.fromJson(str, type);

        for (TesteModel teste : lista) {
            System.out.println(teste.getSelecionado());
            System.out.println(teste.getNome());
        }
        return lista;
    }

    private static String lerArquivo() {
        String linha = "";

        try {
            FileReader arq = new FileReader("C:\\temp\\alunos.json");
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

            linha = lerArq.readLine();
            /*
             * while (linha != null) { System.out.printf(linha); linha = lerArq.readLine();
             * // lê da segunda até a última linha }
             */
            arq.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n", e.getMessage());
        }
        // System.out.println(linha);
        return linha;
    }
}
```

- na classe `TesteTableModel`, o método `deletarLinhas()` pode ser simplificado. Você não precisa varrer item por item de uma lista para apagar tudo, a classe `List` já possui nativamente um método para limpar a lista, que é o [`clear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear--). Por isso é importante SEMPRE ler a documentação das classes, é assim que se aprende seu funcionamento e evita-se criação de código desnecessário para tarefas que o java já possui. Basta usar o método citado e notificar a tabela:

```
public void deletarLinhas() {
    this.dados.clear();
    this.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

- ainda na classe `TesteTableModel`, sugiro criar um construtor conforme abaixo, tendo em vista o que você [disse no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47478275#47478275) a respeito do reuso da tabela para outros arquivos json. Desta forma você pode criar algum botão ou função que importe um novo arquivo e popule ele na tabela, bastando criar um novo `TableModel`:

```
//flexibilizando o tablemodel
public TesteTableModel(List<TesteModel> model) {
    this.dados = model;
}
```

Reforço a dica que dei no chat: **procure sempre entender o básico de como um componente funciona**, java-swing não é uma API tão fácil de manusear assim, apesar de não ser tão complexa, mas é essencial que você procure entender como o componente funciona, quais suas funcionalidades, senão a cada código que achar por ai e tentar adaptá-lo no seu, só vai criar uma cascata de problemas.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez, sua resposta foi perfeita. A solução é realmente muito mais simples tanto de implementar quanto de entender. Agradeço imensamente por não só me ajudar com o problema mas por me ajudar a melhorar o código de maneira geral com suas dicas. Foram muito importantes!