# Como instanciar objetos Strategy?

Tags: java, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, strategy-pattern

Considere a implementação básica do padrão *Strategy*.

```
public class Context{
  private Strategy strategy;
}

public interface Strategy{
  void algoritmo();
}

public class ConcreteStrategyA implements Strategy{
  void algoritmo(){
    // algoritmo A
  }
}

public class ConcreteStrategyB implements Strategy{
  void algoritmo(){
    // algoritmo B
  }
```

A dúvida refere-se ao seu uso, ou seja, como instanciar os objetos `ConcreteStrategyA` e `ConcreteStrategyB`?

Penso na seguintes alternativa: crio o objeto, em uma camada de controle, por exemplo, e repasso para a classe `Context`, na qual invoca o método (polimórfico `algoritmo()`). Mas como saber qual o objeto correto instanciar? Teria que fazer uma lógica (uso de `if`/`else`) para identificar o objeto correto. Mas dessa forma, fazendo uso de estruturas de condição, eu estaria criando um problema que o padrão *Strategy* procura resolver. Correto?

Para deixar mais claro, suponha o seguinte cenário: possuo uma classe `CalculadoraDeTarifas` (`Context`), ela recebe o tipo de veículo (carro, moto, etc) e um período de tempo. Suponha ainda que tenho um *Strategy* `TarifaStrategy` que é a interface para `DiariaMoto`, `DiariaCarro`, `PorHoraMoto`, `PorHoraCarro`, `MensalidadeMoto`, `MensalidadeCarro`, etc.

Considere agora que preciso passar que uma moto permaneceu por um período de 15 horas. Nesse caso, como uma das regras é que, quando o período for superior a 12 horas é cobrado uma "Diária", para moto. Esse cálculo deveria estar no `algoritmo()` de `DiariaMoto`, correto? Se sim, como fazer com que ele seja executado?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Eu tenho uma palestra que falo sobre o mau uso dos chamados *design patterns*. O primeiro problema é que as pessoas não sabem o que são os tais DPs, e para que servem, onde podem ser aplicados, o que pode ser chamado de DP e que eles estão por toda parte, até onde você não os vê. O segundo problema é que as pessoas os estudam, aprendem a solução e aí procuram um problema para aplicá-lo. Isso está errado, você deve ter um problema e achar a melhor solução para ele. Por acaso pode ser um dos DPs.

Se você não sabe como aplicar o padrão de projeto Strategy é porque não precisa dele. Pelo menos não onde está pensando em usar. Se ele é adequado o seu uso é natural e não precisa de seletores, você cria um objeto de acordo com uma demanda e nele passa a estratégia a ser usada, o padrão é só isso. Dependendo do contexto da aplicação será uma estratégia diferente. Eventualmente se chega nesse contexto com um `if` ou `switch`, mas isso é tangencial e secundário, não é o que define a estratégia a ser usada e sim como operar adequadamente naquele contexto.

Com uma pergunta não muito clara não dá para saber o que é mais adequado. Para uma decisão adequada precisa entender todos os requisitos e conhecer toda organização da aplicação. DP não pode ser usado como uma receita de bolo sem contexto. A pergunta fala em estratégias de veículos diferentes, nem sei se faz sentido usar esse DP em um caso assim.

Pra falar a verdade eu duvido que seja o caso de usar o Strategy aí. Me parece que existe um objeto completamente diferente que deve tratar das tarifas, não faz o menor sentido tentar enfiar a tarifa dentro da moto ou carro. Há uma relação entre a tarifa e o veículo e o tempo usado, mas não é o mesmo objeto, uma tarifa é uma propriedade de um veículo, a não ser que a classe específica do veículo sequer seja um veículo e está mal nomeada.

Aí vem a crítica que eu faço à orientação a objeto. Se as pessoas não conseguem dar nomes certos e classificar os objetos corretamente, não tem metodologia ou paradigma que faça o software ser bem escrito. Sem bom entendimento de ontologia e taxonomia não dá para programar OO. Este código parece falhar nesses pontos, então qualquer penduricalho que tente colocar no código já é errado porque está usando uma base errada.

Eu não garanto essas coisas que eu estou colocando aqui porque a pergunta não é clara. Quando não se tem clareza do problema ao ponto de não conseguir descrever o problema em português é mais complicado escrever em Java ou outra linguagem. Todas soluções tem potencial de serem erradas, usando DP ou não.

A outra resposta diz como usar o Strategy DP, mas não diz que isto é o certo a se fazer e espero que não ache que é. Esta forma viola a [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) obrigando uma classe cuidar de coisas que não lhe dizem respeito.

Outro erro conceitual é colocar o Strategy como meio temporário de realizar algo. Este DP foi criado para criar objetos que terão a mesma estratégia por todo seu tempo de vida e não mudar conforme a situação. Novamente, isso até poderia ser o certo se aquilo não for um veículo e sim uma finalização de estadia de um veículo, que é completamente diferente de ser um veículo ou mesmo uma estadia.

A maioria dos problemas que lidamos é sobre composição e OOP manda fazer herança, polimorfismo ou agrupar coisas no mesmo objeto, por isso OOP não funciona bem na maioria dos casos que as pessoas acham que ela é a solução.

Answer (score 3):

> Mas dessa forma, fazendo uso de estruturas de condição, eu estaria criando um problema que o padrão Strategy procura resolver. Correto?

Sim e não.

A utilização da pattern *strategy* é disponibilizar uma interface para uma família de algoritmos. O cliente não se importa com a implementação da interface desde que ela esteja de acordo com a interface. Nesse sentido, sim, o pattern *strategy* procura evitar a necessidade de escolha de uma implementação diretamente na classe que deseja chamar o algoritmo.

Porém, eventualmente temos que inevitavelmente tomar uma decisão sobre qual implementação instanciar. Aí fica um pouco difícil fugir de `ifs`. Nesse caso, sugiro duas abordagens:

- usar a pattern **factory**. Ela tem por objetivo isolar o processo de criação de objetos. Você pode informar o tipo de veículo e período e ela te retorna o algoritmo adequado. Você ainda termina com uma sequência de `if/else` ou `case/switch`, porém, elas estão encapsuladas dentro dessa classe.
- se sua condição de escolha do algoritmo for uma classe, você pode colocar um método que instancia a devida implementação do algoritmo para aquela classe.

```
public interface ICalculoTarifa {
  void calcularTarifa();
}

public interface CalculoTarifaCarro implements ICalculoTarifa {
  public void calcularTarifa(){ 
    //implmentação
  }
}

public interface CalculoTarifaMoto implements ICalculoTarifa {
  public void calcularTarifa(){ 
    //implmentação
  }
}

public interface IVeiculo {
  IAlgoritmo getCalculoTarifa();
}

public interface Carro implements IVeiculo {
  public IAlgoritmo getCalculoTarifa(){
    return new CalculoTarifaCarro();
  }
}

public interface Moto implements IVeiculo {
  public IAlgoritmo getCalculoTarifa(){
    return new CalculoTarifaMoto();
  }
}
```