# O que a classe context faz do padrão de projeto de Estratégia?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, strategy-pattern

Se o Strategy usa sua classe abstrata como um meio de instanciar as implementações concretas, qual a função do `context`? Em certos materiais foi citado que este design patter seria implementado em uma situação como a seguinte:

```
if $banco == "Santander":
   faca algo
else if $banco == "Itau":
   faca outra coisa
  ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que se define como `contexto` nesse padrão é só uma forma genérica de chamar a classe que você vai usar a estratégia. É onde precisa de uma estratégia e possivelmente a escolha qual delas usar.

Por exemplo, se você tiver uma classe `Impostos` ela pode ser o contexto para usar estratégias de acordo com o estado onde teriam implementações de estratégias algo como `ImpostoSP`, `ImpostoRJ`, etc. Nessa classe usa um objeto de um desses tipos de estratégia (eventualmente mais que um se for adequado). Essa classes tratam os impostos de forma geral mas o detalhamento varia em cada estado e ele consome esse detalhe das estratégias.

Só tome cuidado para pegar exemplos ruins e aprender errado. O exemplo do código parece realmente usar o padrão, mas talvez não da maneira mais adequada, mas estou só especulando, não tenho informação suficiente para afirmar.

Mais informações em [Como instanciar objetos Strategy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/350166/101).