# Por que não pode acessar um atributo de uma classe na classe herdada?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Tenho esta classe:

```
package auladezoitodonove;


public class Conta {


    // atributos
    private int numeroConta;
    private String nomeCliente;
    private int identificador;

    //Construtores
    void Conta (){
       numeroConta = ++identificador;
    }
    void Conta(String cliente){
        numeroConta = ++identificador;
        nomeCliente = cliente;
    }
```

E essa outra classe herdando da classe `Conta`:

```
package auladezoitodonove;

public class ContaCorrente extends Conta{
    private int taxa;

    public ContaCorrente(String cliente, int taxa) {
        super(nomeCliente);

        nomeCliente = cliente;
        this.taxa = taxa;
    }
```

Não consigo entender porque não é possível herdar os atributos da classe `Conta` para `ContaCorrente`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu vejo alguns problemas na modelagem, mas vou me concentrar na pergunta feita.

[O que chama de atributos na verdade se chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

A herança está ocorrendo. As pessoas não entendem herança e por isso acham que alguma coisa não é herdada, mas herança herda **tudo** o que a mãe tem, inclusive qualquer coisa que ela já herdou. Então está herdando tudo.

A pergunta não está especialmente clara mas acho que dá para inferir que tentou acessar na classe filha um campo declarado na classe mãe e deve ter dado algum erro. Pois bem, os campos da classe mãe foram declarado com **visibilidade** privada (`private`) e portanto só são `**visíveis** em código da classe mãe. Não quer dizer que o campo não existe na classe filha, apenas o código dela não pode acessar.

A solução é aumentar a visibilidade do campo. Uma forma que alguns fariam é torná-los `public`, mas pode ser que não deseje isto, é visibilidade muito ampla. Então pode fazer o meio termo, pode fazer com que o campo seja visível nas classes filhas sem tornar-se público, isto se dá através do modificador de visibilidade `protected`. Mas cuidado sem ter muita consciência do seu uso poderá fazer coisas erradas e violar vários princípios da orientação a objeto (não que não possa fazer isto, mas precisa entender o que está fazendo, não é só fazer funcionar) ou princípios gerais de *design*, como o [acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Answer (score -1):

Perceba que esta Declarando os atributos como "**private**" assim esses mesmo nao seram acessíveis fora da classe,ou seja se herdar a classe que herda nao tem acesso, Mas...
Se você utilizar os Métodos Assessores (Getter e setter) Acredito que resolva o problema.