# Manipulando classe dentro de outra classe e salvar em array

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, instanciar-objeto

Criei uma classe `Pessoa` e nela um atributo `endereco`, só que fiz uma classe `Endereco` para cadastrar mais de um `endereco` por pessoa.

Nessa outra classe `Endereco` tem `id` e `nome da rua`, e não consigo manipular elas da classe `Pessoa`.

Quero salvar os dois junto em um mesmo *array*.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoa = new ArrayList<>();

        Pessoa c1 = new Pessoa();
        c1.setId(1);
        c1.setNome("Pedro");
        c1.setEndereco(endereco);//Erro, nao consigo manipular para por o nome da rua e nem o id

        System.out.println(c1.getEndereco());

        pessoa.add(c1);
}

public class Pessoa {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private Endereco endereco;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

}

public class Endereco {

    private int id;
    private String rua;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRua() {
        return rua;
    }

    public void setRua(String rua) {
        this.rua = rua;
    }

}
```

Comment: Você declara a variável `endereco` aonde na função main? Não teria que criar um ArrayList de endereço e um objeto de Pessoa?

Comment: Tipo, quero um array que possa cadastrar varios endereco se precisar. Mais o Endereco que esta em outra classe possa ser salvo na sequencia certa do array de pessoa.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro vamos combinar que [o que você chama de atributo na verdade se chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Você tem que criar um objeto `Endereco` no seu código e aí passar esse objeto para o objeto `Pessoa`, nem precisaria criar uma variável que você criou mas não só não colocou um valor nele, mas nem a declarou. Claro que na forma que está fazendo a variável será necessária, mas só porque todo o código está conceitualmente errado, por exemplo deveria usar [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) (não vou entrar sobre o abuso de *getter* e principalmente *setter*, mas pesquise aqui mesmo no site sobre o assunto).

Seria mais ou menos assim:

```
var endereco = new Endereco();
endereco.setId(1); // sei lá se isso deveria existir e se deveria ser livre assim
endereco.setRua("rua");
c1.setEndereco(endereco);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/InstanceMember.java).

Endereço não tem só **rua**, este é outro conceito bastante errado. Claro que isso importa pouco para exercício mas é bom saber. Na verdade [as pessoas erram muito sobre endereços](https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#postal-addresses).

Se deseja um objeto para cadastrar uma lista de pessoa**s**, então a variável deveria se chamar `pessoas`, certo?

Se deseja cadastrar mais de um endereço por pessoa então terá que ter um campo com uma lista de endereços, o que faz o código ser muito diferente deste que está usando, e aí precisa rever esses *setters* e provavelmente *getters*. Por isso que eu digo para nunca usar um conceito que não entende, só porque as pessoas estão usando, talvez elas também não entendem porque usaram, ou podem entender e fazerem certo, enquanto os demais não conseguirão o mesmo.

É bem complicado manter a [coesão e baixo acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) com o que quer fazer mantendo preceitos de OOP. Então a classe `Pessoa` só deveria lidar com esse *array*, de forma indireta para não expor detalhes de implementação e a classe `Endereco` cuidar de todo o resto dele.

Comment: Minha ideia era fazer assim 
Pessoa c1 = new Pessoa(1, "Pedro",endereco);
Porem travei como por o endereco que esta em outra classe e poder modificar ele.

Comment: é, seria melhor assim, mas não foi o que fez.