# Problema de performance ao declarar variáveis

Tags: javascript, variáveis, desempenho

Estou fazendo um código que uma função muito grande, onde declaro algumas variáveis locais com `const` e `let`. Para melhorar a leitura dele estou dividindo esta função em várias funções pequenas. Então acabei por declarar dentro do escopo dessas funções, as variáveis novamente. O que antes eram, por exemplo, 5 variáveis locais, agora se multiplicaram em 50 ou mais variáveis locais dentro dessas funções.

O que é melhor?

1 - Declarar essas variáveis com `let` e `const` uma única vez fora do escopo das funções. E depois ir somente atribuindo novos valores nessas variáveis dentro das funções (com exceção de `const`).

```
let thisHelp = null;
let thisSymbol = null;
let thisText = null;

function myFunction() {
  thisHelp = SceneManager._scene._helpWindow;
  thisSymbol = SceneManager._scene._categoryWindow.currentSymbol();
  thisText = Eli.Param.HelpWindows.menuText
  thisHelp.x = 100;
};

function myFuntion2() {
  thisHelp = SceneManager._scene._helpWindow;
  thisSymbol = SceneManager._scene._categoryWindow.currentSymbol();
  thisText = Eli.Param.HelpWindows.etc;
  thisHelp.x = 100;
};
```

2 - Fazer do mesmo jeito, declarar e atribur um valor as variáveis somente dentro das funções.

```
function myFunction() {
  const thisHelp = SceneManager._scene._helpWindow;
  const thisSymbol = SceneManager._scene._categoryWindow.currentSymbol();
  const thisText = Eli.Param.HelpWindows.menuText
  thisHelp.x = 100;
};

function myFuntion2() {
  const thisHelp = SceneManager._scene._helpWindow;
  const thisSymbol = SceneManager._scene._categoryWindow.currentSymbol();
  const thisText = Eli.Param.HelpWindows.etc;
  thisHelp.x = 100;
}
```

3 - Estou me preocupando muito e isso para JavaScript não é uma questão com relação a performance. Ou seja, posso fazer de qualquer jeito.

Comment: Se você quer verificar a performance entre duas alternativas, onde o resultado não é óbvio, meça o tempo gasto para executar cada opção (v.g use console.time() e console.timeend()). À parte isso, o problema do seu exemplo, é que as pessoas que trabalham com você ou dependem do seu código vão olhar para o primeiro caso, ver três variáveis globais sem uma necessidade clara e já irem ficarem muito pê da vida.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não tem problema nenhum de performance você fazer designações. Provavelmente até os compiladores otimizam isso.

Ok, chutando uma resposta, mais relacionada a padrões de programação em geral.

É muito comum um conjunto de funções compartilharem um mesmo **contexto** ou **estado**. Existem várias formas com que você pode compartilhar um mesmo contexto entre várias funções sem repetição de código. Qual delas é a melhor? Não sei, é muito uma questão de gosto.

### Agrupamento

Se você tem um conjunto de variáveis comuns, você pode agrupá-la em um objeto. E daí você passa esse objeto como parâmetro para diversas funções.

```
fn1(estado, a, b, c)
fn2(estado, 1, 2)
fn3(estado, x, y)
```

### Classes

Uma classe é um **container de estado**. Funções (métodos) de uma classe compartilham as mesmas variáveis. Escreveríamos o código acima na seguinte forma com classes:

```
const grupo = new MyClass(estado)
grupo.fn1(a, b, c)
grupo.fn2(1, 2)
grupo.fn3(x, y)
```

### Closures

Funções também são containers de estado devido à forma de funcionamento do chamado "escopo léxico". O uso de uma função pra guardar estado é comumente chamado de "closure". É uma forma um pouco diferente de escrever pra atingir um resultado similar ao uso de classes.

```
function MeuGrupo(estado) {
  return {
    fn1(a, b, c) { ... },
    fn2(a, b) { ... },
    fn3(x, y) { ... }
  }
}

const grupo = MeuGrupo(estado)
grupo.fn1(a,b,c)
grupo.fn2(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser que o códigos postado não seja o mesmo que está usando, mas neste caso não vi muita diferença real em fazer de um jeito ou de outro do ponto de vista de digitação ou legibilidade. Este código não lida com o objeto definido em uma classe, o que aí seria diferente.  Não posso falar de algo que poderia ser se tivesse sido feito certo porque a pergunta é sobre este código assim. Não sei se este é u mcaso de criar uma classe (ou protótipo).

Na verdade só vejo desvantagens no primeiro caso. Além de usar estado com escopo global que costuma ser ruim fica menos legível principalmente em código grande porque a declaração da variável não fica onde ela está sendo usada. Pior ainda ser obrigado torná-la variável quando da outra forma pode ser constante.

Em *scripts* escopo global não costuma ser problema, mas hoje as pessoas usam JS para fazer aplicações, aí pesa.

A pergunta diz não se preocupar com desempenho, mas coloca a *tag* deste assunto, então se preocupa e nem sabe. O estado global tem desempenho pior, mesmo que a diferença seja irrisória e não há como o compilador, ainda de uma linguagem interpretada fazer uma otimização deste tipo.

O padrão de nomes adotado é bem esquisito e pode gerar confusão.

O problema todo deve ter começado quando tentou dividir a função em várias, isto fez perder a [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) e causou um problema que a gora está tentando consertar, mas não seria melhor consertar o real problema que não existia antes, portanto voltar ao que era? Provavelmente leu que deve dividir em funções pequenas e agora está tentando aplicar como se fosse uma receita de bolo.

Boa parte das pessoas que trabalham na área não sabem programar de verdade porque elas seguem receita de bolo, é importante você entender os porquês de cada coisa que inventam por aí, desta forma pode ser crítico e determinar quando usar algo e quando evitar. Boa parte das coisas que as pessoas dizem que é para fazer só se aplica em alguns casos, mas muitos aprendem que deve ser em todos.

Por outro lado o que foi postado pode dar indicações erradas do que está fazendo de verdade, aí minha resposta seria outra.